# LaTeX Error: Environment example undefined

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style, ieeeconf

I need to use the keyword `example` in IEEEtran template but I get this error:

```
Error: LaTeX Error: Environment example undefined.
Error: LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{example}.
```

Here is my test script:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\begin{example} Here is my example \end{example}

\end{document}
```

Can you clarify how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try `\newtheorem{example}{Example}`, eventually after `\usepackage{amsthm}`, but the LaTeX core does provide `\newtheorem` already and it is not likely that `IEEEtran` disables this

Comment: Use `ieeeconf` class instead for IEEE conferences

Answer (score 2):

You have to define your theorem-like environments with `\newtheorem`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\begin{document}
\begin{example} Here is my example \end{example}
\end{document}
```

[image]